Inserting boxed material in the background without affecting layout
I am wrapping text around a figure manually using \smash and changing \rightskip.
It mostly works, except for some unwanted extra vertical space that is inserted.
Here is a simplified example:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

111

222

\smash{\vtop{\noindent\hspace*{1cm}333\\\hspace*{1cm}444}}

333

444

\end{document}

The "smashed" box goes into background, but an extra text line is created:

How can I create and insert as a "background" a (zero-height zero-depth) box with arbitrary material at a given place in vertical mode without affecting the vertical positions of the rest?

Is this what you want? Try \rlap and \smash:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

111

222\rlap{\smash{\vtop{\noindent\color{red}\hspace*{1cm}333\\\hspace*{1cm}444}}} you should see the overlay contents

333 here shows the overlap either

444

\end{document}



I meant the insertion to happen in vertical mode, outside of paragraphs. The inserted material should be logically between elements of the vertical list.

After some experimenting, I think I've found a solution based on Exercise 21.1 in The TeXbook:
\documentclass{article}
\newlength{\savedPrevdepth}
\begin{document}

111

222

\setlength{\savedPrevdepth}{\prevdepth}
\nointerlineskip
\smash{\vtop{\noindent\\\hspace*{1cm}333\\\hspace*{1cm}444}}
\setlength{\prevdepth}{\savedPrevdepth}

333

444

\end{document}


